# Countable product of second countable spaces

Tags: general-topology

I am reading the proof that a countable product of second countable spaces is second countable at the following link:

http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2002&task=show_msg&msg=0379.0002

The part that eludes me is:

"If now $O$ is any open set in the product $X$, and $x \in O$, then
there is a standard product open set $V$ containing $x$ inside $O$.
This set depends on finitely many coordinates, so $V = \prod_n V_n$
where only finitely many $V_n$ are unequal to $X_n$."

Could anybody help me and elaborate why would such a $V$ exist? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

That is the definition of product topology. The product topology in $X_1\times X_2\times...$ is the one generated by sets of the form $U_1\times U_2\times...$ where each $U_i$ is open in $X_i$ for each $i$ and $U_n=X_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The standard base for the product topology is the set of all sets of the form $\prod_n O_n$, where all $O_n$ are open in $X_n$ and the set $\{n: O_n \neq X_n\}$ is finite. This follows from the usual definition of the product topology as the smallest topology that makes all projections $p_m: \prod_n X_n \to X_m$ continuous; this forces all finite intersections of sets $p_{m_1}^{-1}[O_{m_i}]$ (where $m_i \in \Bbb N, O_m \subseteq X_m$ open) to be in the product topology (and these are exactly those product sets I described), and by minimality these form a base: all open sets are unions of such sets.

So if $O$ is product-open and $x \in O$, $x$ must lie in some product $\prod_n O_n$ as described (that is one of the basic open sets that union up to $O$).